# Using roots of unity mod n to break rsa when e and phi are not coprime

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, roots-of-unity

I am trying to solve an rsa problem where **we only know the public key (n,e) and the ciphertext c**.

The **modulus n is** actually **a prime number**, **so** we can easily compute phi as **phi = n-1**.

But the problem is that **e shares a common factor with phi**, where gcd(e,phi) = 8 , where gcd = greatest common divisor. **So this means we can't get the private key d**. Also e is a power of 2 (e = 16).

In my research I found that **this problem has to do with something called "roots of unity modulo n"**. So basically if I compute all roots of unity I can get all possible plaintexts. But **i can't seem to be able to understand the concept of "roots of unity mod n"** and how this helps find all possible plaintexts.

**Could someone please explain to me this** ?

Comment: If you know $e$ and $\phi$ then can you not easily compute the private key? I think it is the inverse of $e$ modulo $\phi$.

Comment: @JosephHarrison I can't in this example because e and phi shares a common factor (meaning gcd(e,phi) != 1). This problem is solved by roots of unity mod n.

Comment: $n$ is not prime in RSA.

Comment: @bd55 in that case, there is no private key. This system is unsuitable for cryptographic application, because it will be impossible to recover encrypted messages